# Why does the use of getline lead to "Debug assertion failed" message when setmodes are set as well?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, getline

So when debugging the code below I get a "Debug assertion failed" error window with the message:

```
Expression: ( (_Stream->_flag & _IOSTRG) || (fn = _fileno(_Stream), 
(_textmode_safe(fn) == __IOINFO_TM_ANSI) && !_tm_unicode_safe(fn))))
```

However, if I comment out setmode lines, there is no problem at all.

Debugging always breaks at the line consisting getline. How should I modify the code to be able to scan data with getline?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);

    std::string myString;
    getline(std::cin, myString);
    std::cout << "You typed in " << myString << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which of the the subexpressions of the assertion evaluate to which value? How about using `std::wcin`? How about removing the calls to `_setmode()`? In any case, you are deep, deep in implementation-defined behaviour, so check the documentation of the particular compiler you are using. Also, add that compiler and its version to the question.

Comment: What are these `_setmode` whatsits? Can you point to the documentation? Why don't you use standard features?

Comment: @lazarea: Add the details TO THE QUESTION. Not in the comments section. To the _question_.

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be setting some kind of UTC-16 mode on STDIN, wouldn't it make more sense to read from [`std::wcin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) (the wide-character version of `std::cin`) into a [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)? It's conceivable that this implementation-specific, non-standard feature has a requirement in that regard.

All the evidence I can find online (which isn't much) shows that [this is the recommended approach for this mode](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/992713/visual-c-bug-with-console-input).